# Api retrofit для андроид приложения, несколько запросов для одной активити, как правильно сделать?

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

я изучаю андроид и пытаюсь написать  приложение-соц. сеть столкнулся с такой проблемой.

В приложении есть страница профиля пользователя где выводится инфа о пользователе и комментарии к его странице(а-ля стена)

В тоже время у меня есть сайт с api с которого приложение получает данные

В api есть 2 метода /getUserInfo(для получения инфы о пользователе) и getUserComments(для получения списка комментов на стене пользователя)

Сейчас при открытии активити профиля мне нужно делать 2 запроса к сайту, чтобы получить нужную инфу и вывести её в приложении

Вопрос вот в чем - будет ли правильно объединить 2 метода api в 1 (например /getProfileData) и получать в 1 запросе сразу все данные которые нужно вывести в активити

Я знаю как сделать и тем и другим способом, интересует как будет правильнее, так как при объединении запросов у меня получается какая-то каша из сущностей

Answer (score 0):

лучше разделить. В дальнейшем могут понадобиться отдельно инфа о пользователе и отдельно комментарии. Плюс - это все таки разные сущности.

Answer (score 0):

Для более качественного кода как со стороны бекенда, так и со стороны клиента будет лучше если ты разделишь их на два метода. Так у тебя будет разделение отвтетственности между двумя методами.